# Serializing a java object

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to serialize java objects but i keep getting a list of errors. my program accepts multiple values and creates an instance of a class with them. the created object then gets stored in a StorageSystem class... it looks something like this

```
    aCD = new CD(title, artist, playTime, numOfTracks);
    store.addItem(aCD);
```

Then in the storage system i add the stored object to an arrayList... what i also want to do is add the object to a serialized file... my method for doing this is below... Am i going about this the wrong way. thanks...

```
public void addItem(Item hold)                      // adds object to the ArrayList
{
    itemList.add(hold);

    totalStored++;

    FileOutputStream f_out;
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("thequeue.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(hold);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Know what the errors are would help a whole lot.

Answer (score 2):

Code appears 'ok' . Theses are my observations :

1. Your class must implement the Serializable interface
2. FileOutputStream f_out; is never read
3. Instead of appending single object why don’t you put the entire ArrayList  i.e  (itemList) to the
   object output stream
4. Catch 'IOException' first before trying 'Exception'

Answer (score 1):

Code seems ok, except a double, unclear decaration (first `f_out` then `fout` declared and used).

Are you sure that classes that you want to serialize do implement the `Serializable` tag interface? In anycase I suggest you to write the whole `ArrayList` to the object output stream instead that trying to append single objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not going to do what you *want* because every time you open the `FileOutputStream` it's going to overwrite the last file -- so you'll always have exactly one item in the file.

Also, your `FileOutputStream` is named `f_out` when you declare it outside the scope of the `try`, but you then create another one named `fout` inside that scope.

I'm not exactly sure what happens if you close the `ObjectOutputStream` instead of the `FileOutputStream` -- I *think* it should close the `FileOutputStream` but I'm not sure.